# Prohibition against entering the bedroom of a married couple?

Tags: halacha

My local Rabbi told be that it is forbidden to enter the bedroom of a married couple. What is the source for this? Does this only apply to a couple whose marriage is recognised by Jewish law? When does this prohibition cease (like a widow for example?) At what age does this prohibition take effect (boys over the age of 9?)

Comment: אמר רב המנונא בריה דרב יוסף זימנא חדא הוה קאימנא קמיה דרבא ואמר לי זיל אייתי לי תפילין ואשכחתינהו בין כר לכסת שלא כנגד ראשו והוה ידענא [ב] דיום טבילה הוה ולאגמורן הלכה למעשה הוא דעבד

Comment: תניא אמר רבי עקיבא פעם אחת נכנסתי אחר ר' יהושע לבית הכסא ולמדתי ממנו ג' דברים למדתי שאין נפנין מזרח ומערב אלא צפון ודרום ולמדתי שאין נפרעין מעומד אלא מיושב ולמדתי שאין מקנחין בימין אלא בשמאל אמר ליה בן עזאי עד כאן העזת פניך ברבך א"ל תורה היא וללמוד אני צריך

Comment: תניא בן עזאי אומר פעם אחת נכנסתי אחר רבי עקיבא לבית הכסא ולמדתי ממנו ג' דברים למדתי שאין נפנין מזרח ומערב אלא צפון ודרום ולמדתי שאין נפרעין מעומד אלא מיושב ולמדתי שאין מקנחין בימין אלא בשמאל אמר לו ר' יהודה עד כאן העזת פניך ברבך אמר לו תורה היא וללמוד אני צריך רב כהנא על גנא תותיה פורייה דרב שמעיה דשח ושחק ועשה צרכיו אמר ליה דמי פומיה דאבא כדלא שריף תבשילא א"ל כהנא הכא את פוק דלאו אורח ארעא אמר לו תורה היא וללמוד אני צריך

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps due to this Rashi in Succah 21:

> להכי נקט גבי מטה מנעלים וסנדלים דאמרי' בבבא בתרא (דף נח.) איזהו מטה של תלמידי חכמים. כל שאין תחתיה אלא מנעלים של בעל הבית בימות החמה וסנדלים בימות הגשמים שנותנים שם כשהוא בא לשכב ולישן חולץ מנעליו ונותנן תחת מטתו אבל לתת תחתיה דברים אחרים גנאי הוא לו שמרגיל בני הבית לשם

Seemingly it is offensive to hang around there. The Rashbam in Bava Basra explains it differently, though. He connects it to Ruach Ra.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming he is referring to the gemara in Eiruvin 63b Rav Bruna said in the name of Rav whoever sleeps in the room of a husband and his wife are gets the passuk from Micha 2 'the women of my nation are sent from their house of enjoyment'. Rashi explains that they are embarrassed from their guest. Presumably meaning the problem is they won't be intimate, as that is what the previous section was discussing.

But Rav Yosef adds one should not sleep there even if the wife is a nida. Maharsha explains in the name of Rabi Yehonason that the problem is they will be embarrassed to talk about private matters.

Comment: So this seems to only apply to sleeping? Is there anything about not even entering?

Comment: The only thing I've ever seen about not entering was in a Rav Mattisyahu Solomon book, probably hearts full of love, where he says children should never ever enter their parents bedroom. I think he said it should be like a mikdash to them. Um, he's English. This might be a  European outlook on life. I dunno. But the gemara is admonishing disrupting the private life of a couple. That's the basic idea.

Comment: This seems to also contradict what my rabbi said (should probably add this to the question) that ONLY children are allowed to enter!

Comment: I kinda always understood the Niddah/talking to be less about ability to speak of 'sex'-related things and more just about having their personal space to decompress from the day and feel closeness-togetherness. Consider the Arukh haShulchan's formulation of כי יש לה תענוג כשהיא בחדר אחד עם בעלה.

Comment: @Double I feel the same. Especially considering the whole chayav lifkod ishto before a trip being taken as shmoozing when the need be. I tried to phrase my words accordingly.

Comment: @Double but what a.h. are you referring to?

Comment: @user6591 OC 240:3

Comment: I would add that it also refers to eating. The Satmar rebbe used to eat privately with his wife daily. But perhaps that is because he almost never slept with her.

Comment: @DoubleAA You must be right, since they aren't supposed to be discussing those issues at that time anyhow.

Comment: @HaLeiVi Divrei Hergel is different from Divrei Tashmish. What if the husband needs to ask for an update to expected Mikva date or planning activities/dinner thereon? Or about a psak from a recent bedika? Or even just planning how they have access to a place to have Biah that coming weekend (after her Mikva dip on Thursday) at a cousin's out of town Simcha? Not Divrei Hergel, but sufficiently about sex to make one uncomfortable around others.