# Is there a halacha forbidding a guest to enter the host's unoccupied bedroom?

Tags: halacha

Several of my friends as well as a few of my neighbors do not allow anyone outside the immediate family to enter their bedroom even when it is empty. (Occasionally, when visiting a friend who recently bought or updated their home, I am curious to see how they decorated their bedroom - sometimes it gives me ideas on how to do mine.)

All these people said that the bedroom is halichally considered a private place and one is forbidden to invade another person's private, personal space.

I can understand the concept of the privacy, overall. But I'm curious if there is any halacha per se that would prohibit seeing an unoccupied bedroom.

**Note:** [This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59932/prohibition-against-entering-the-bedroom-of-a-married-couple) focuses on the type of marriage that would allow or prohibit this action. My question assumes only a valid Jewish marriage, and asks specifically about an unoccupied bedroom.

*(Other than halacha, I'm not sure how to tag this question; please assist / edit)*